# How to fix "Assertion failed: new_time >= loop->time, file c:\ws\deps\uv\src\win\core.c, line 309" error?

Tags: windows-10, laptop, bios, cmd.exe, node.js

I have a HP laptop with Windows 10 and when I use node.js (v 12.14.0) I get this error:

```
"Assertion failed: new_time >= loop->time, file c:\ws\deps\uv\src\win\core.c, line 309".
```

I read from this [github post](https://github.com/libuv/libuv/issues/1633) that it can be solved by resetting the CMOS and so I did by doing "Load Setups Default" on the BIOS but it didn't work.

How can I fix this problem?

I know that there are some posts on this argument on stack but none of them was hepful to me.

Comment: I have read it may be a BIOS update that is needed. Or Intel Driver update: https://github.com/heroku/cli/issues/1354

Answer (score 0):

Solved:
I had the same issue with firebase on Windows 10. I simply synchronized the clock. There is a button called "Synchronize Your Clock" under Date & Time settings. And the issue got resolved.